# What is a lift?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

What exactly is a lift? I wanted to prove that for appropriately chosen topological groups $G$ we can show that the completion of $\widehat{G}$ is isomorphic to the inverse limit $$\lim_{\longleftarrow} G/G_n$$

I wasn't sure how to construct the map so I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175483/isomorphism-from-widehatg-to-displaystyle-lim-longleftarrow-g-g-n) to which I got an answer but I don't understand it. Searching for "lift" or "inverse limit lift" has not helped and I was quite sure that if $[x] \in \widehat{G}$ I could just "project" $x_n$ to $$\lim_{\longleftarrow} G/G_n$$ using the map $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \pi_n (x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ in $G/G_n$. Would someone help me finish this construction and explain to me what a lift is? Thank you.

**Edit**

I don't know any category theory. An explanation understandable by someone not knowing any category theory would be very kind.

Comment: In my answer I addressed the question 'what is a lift' in general. I think questions about this particular case (completion of a topological group) should be asked in the thread you mention.

Comment: @wildildildlife No, the person who answered is on leave so no one is going to look there and see my comments.

Comment: Is this related to [the lifting scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_scheme) for wavelets?

Comment: @bobobobo I don't know.

Comment: Given ƒ: X→Z and g₂: Y→Z, we ask for g₁: X→Z that factors through g₂.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the Wikipedia article on lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28mathematics%29):

In a category $C$, let be given two arrows $f,g$ with codomain $Z$. A *lift* (of $f$ with respect to $g$) is an arrow $F$ such that $g\circ F =f$. So it is a morphism from $f$ to $g$ in the [over category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category) $C/Z$.

**Motivation**: the idea is that $g:X\to Z$ indicates the *vertical*  direction pointing *down*: $X$ lies *above* $Z$ via $g$. Think of $g$ as a fibre bundle, or covering map, or vertical projction. So a given $f:Y\to Z$ takes values in the *lower* space; and to *lift* $f$ (via $g$) means to 'let it take values in the *upper* space': find a 'modified' $F:Y\to X$ such that, after vertically projecting its values, we get $f$ back; in other words $p\circ F=f$. If we take $Y=[0,1]$ this is *path-lifting*.

In particular:

- a lift of the identity $id:Z\to Z$ (via $g:X\to Z$) is an arrow $s:Z\to X$ such that $g\circ s=id$, i.e. a [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28category_theory%29) of $g$.

(I believe in your case this is meant: a section of a quotient map $q:X\to X/\sim$ is a map $s:X/\sim\to X$ such that $s[x]\sim x$. One could say that $s[x]\in X$ is a lift of $[x]$.)

DUALLY: let be given two arrows $f,g$ with domain $Z$. A *lift* of $f$ (via $g$) is an arrow $F$ such that $F\circ f=g$. So it is a morphism from $f$ to $g$ in the [under category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category) $Z/C$.

**Motivation**: again the idea is that $g:Z\to X$ indicates the *vertical*  direction, but now pointing *up*: $X$ lies *above* $Z$ via $g$. Think of $g$ as an 
inclusion; then:

- a lift of $f:Y\to X$ (via an *inclusion* $g:Z\to X$) is an arrow $F:Y\to X$ such that $F\circ i=g$, i.e. an *extension* of $f$.

Related concepts are [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object) and [projective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_object) objects. Moreover note that lifts need not exist in general (see also Zhen Lin's comment).

Comment: You should probably mention that, in most cases, the lift lives in the category of sets. For example, the identity map $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ has no lift with respect to the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ in the category of groups.

Comment: What is $C/Z$ and what is $Z/C$?

Comment: Also, if $f: A \to B$ and $g : C \to B$, shouldn't a lift of $f$ be a map that lifts $f$ to $C$, i.e. a map $h: C \to A$ such that $fh = g$?

Comment: @ClarkKent: I have added some details, which I hope answer your questions.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @wildildildlife: The dual of a lift is usually called an _extension_, whether or not $g$ is an inclusion.

Comment: So a lift does not have to be continuous? Most definitions on the internet speak of lifts of continuous maps.

Comment: Perhaps if the category is $\mathbf{Top}$, the arrows are continuous maps?

Answer (score 8):

The term lift is merely meant to mean the following. Given a surjective map $G\to G'$ a lift of an element $x\in G'$ is a choice of $y\in G$ such that $y\mapsto x$ under this map.

In the linked answer you have $(x_n)\in \lim G/G_n$. Thus the notation has $x_n\in G/G_n$. The elements $y_n$ are just chosen preimages of $x_n$ under the natural surjection $G\to G/G_n$.