# If an operator is continuous at a point, it is continuous everywhere

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a linear operator on normed vector spaces $T:\mathcal{D}(T)\subset X \rightarrow Y$, if it is continuous at one point $x_0 \in \mathcal{D}(T)$ then it is continuous for all points in $\mathcal{D}(T)$.

I am following Kreyszig intro to functional analysis, he uses boundedness iff continuous to prove this, which is a fine proof. I came up with another proof that I am curious to see if it is correct:

Since $T$ is continuous at $x_0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$||x_0-x||<\delta \implies ||Tx_0 - Tx|| < \epsilon.$$
By translation invariance of the norm (edit: here I mean the translation invariance of the induced distance under the norm), this implies
$$||x_0+d-(x+d)||<\delta \implies ||T(x_0+d) - T(x+d)|| < \epsilon.$$
Since $d\in \mathcal{D}(T)$ is arbitrary, $x_0+d$ can be element in $\mathcal{D}(T)$ that we like. Hence, $T$ is continuous at $x_0+d$, whatever it may be.

I am worried about this proof, because it doesn't seem to use linearity?

Comment: @jcm your proof is fine.  Ignore comments showing identical proofs with some variable substitution claiming there is something wrong with yours.

Comment: Your proof is fine, but you did use linearity. Assume that $\|(x_0+d)-(x+d)\|<\delta$. This is equivalent to $\|x_0-x\|<\delta$. Then this implies that $\epsilon>\|Tx_0-Tx\|=\|Tx_0 +Td - Tx - Td\|=\|T(x_0+d)-T(x+d)\|$. In the last equality you used a little less than linearity. You used additivity.

Comment: That shows that rather than linearity what was important is that $T$ was a group homomorphism between the topological groups $(D(X),+)$ and $(Y,+)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318867/917479)

Comment: Right, @plop I see where I implicitly used linearity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"By translation invariance of the norm, this implies..." No it doesn't. Your hypothesis is that $T$ is continuous at $x_0$. You cannot use a different $x_0$ in

> If $\|x_0-x\|<\delta \implies \|Tx_0 - Tx\| < \epsilon$.

But it works if you use linearity. If $\|x_1-x\|<\delta$, then $\|x_0-(x_0-x_1+x)\|<\delta$. Then
$$
\|Tx_0-T(x_0-x_1+x)\|<\epsilon, 
$$
which the linearity of $T$ lets you write as
$$
\|Tx_1-Tx\|<\epsilon. 
$$

Comment: I never used a different $x_0$, I simply wrote $x_0 = x_0+d -d$.

Comment: But then you used linearity of $T$, and the argument is the same as I wrote.

Comment: Correct, I have used linearity. Initially I didn't see where I applied it. Thanks.